# Display Ajax return info Colorbox

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, colorbox

I'm using Ajax in a HTML page to get a URL from a PHP file. I want to use the obtained URL to show with Colorbox.

Index.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showResult(str)
        {
                if (str.length==0)
                {
                    document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
                    document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
                    return;
                }

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)              // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                {
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else                                    // code for IE6, IE5
                {
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)   // 4- Peticion completada
                    {
                        document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                        document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
                    }
                }

            xmlhttp.open("GET","livesearch.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();

        }
    </script>


<link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements
        $("a[rel='example1']").colorbox();
        $("a[rel='example2']").colorbox({transition:"fade"});
        $("a[rel='example3']").colorbox({transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%"});
        $("a[rel='example4']").colorbox({slideshow:true});
        $(".example5").colorbox();
        $(".example6").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344});
        $(".example7").colorbox({width:"80%", height:"80%", iframe:true});
        $(".example8").colorbox({width:"50%", inline:true, href:"#inline_example1"});
        $(".example9").colorbox({
            onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
            onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
            onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
            onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
            onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
        });

        //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
        $("#click").click(function(){ 
            $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Livesearch.php

```
<?php 
    $variable = $_REQUEST['q'];  
    $response = ""; 

    if(strcmp($variable,"taj")==0)
    {    
      $response = "<p><a href='http://www.viajes-blog.com/wp-content/uploads/taj-mahal-agra-india.jpg' rel='example1' title=''>Taj Mahal</a></p>";
    }
    else
    {
      $response = "no picture found";
    }
    //output the response
    echo $response;
?>
```

I'm able to get the URL but not able to open the image with Colorbox.
Perhaps is a CSS problem but I can't find the error.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can compare strings in PHP with equality operator, no need to use `strcmp()` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.colorbox({href:Livesearch.php,innerWidth:560,innerHeight:400, open:true});
```

Answer (score -2):

http://api.jquery.com/load/
It is more intuitive than native JS )